# How can I import an npm module from a parent directory?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Given the following project structure:

```
- parentPrj
 - prj1
  - node_modules
  - package.json
  - index.js
 - prj2
  - node_modules
  - package.json
 - node_modules
  - react
   - react.js
 - package.json
```

Is it possible to import inside the sources of prj1 the dependencies from `node_modules` of the parent? If yes - how? Currently it gives an error `Unable to resolve module`

In this concrete example, how can I import `react.js` from `index.js`

Comment: Can you provide more context and a concrete example? `parentPrj/pr1/foo.js` wants to import `parentPrj/node_modules/bar.js`?

Comment: @FelixKling, yes, gimme a sec

Comment: Why not just add the dependency to the package.json of the project that requires it?

Comment: @HereticMonkey prj1 and prj2 both require it. don't want to update them separately, if it's possible to avoid this

Comment: sounds like a use-case for https://github.com/lerna/lerna or yarn workspaces

Comment: @m_callens, I'll check it out, but it would be better be honest to do it without any tool. thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) (which was already mentioned in one of the comments), the simplest solution is probably to create a symlink from project A's `node_modules` folder to the parent one.